# Finding A Matrix For A Specific Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I have am studying Linear Algebra, and one of our homework assignments is this:

> Find a matrix representation for the linear operator $F = \frac d{dx}$ with the orthonormal basis
>
> $$Y_0 = \frac 3{\sqrt{5}} \\ Y_1 = \sqrt{\frac 83}x \\ Y_2 = \frac 52(5x^2-1)$$

We are also supposed to use the scalar product:

$$\langle F,G\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 F^*G\,dx$$

But I am not sure how to go about this problem. What do I call $F$ and what do I call $G$. Please make the explanations clear, I really want to learn how to work with this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what that integral is supposed to mean, but it doesn't really matter.  The matrix representation of an operator has nothing to do with an inner product.  You just need to find $FY_0$, $FY_1$, and $FY_2$ in terms of $Y_0$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$.  Alternatively you can find the matrix in the standard basis and then do a change of basis.

Comment: Hi Bye World, the (-1,1) is the limits on the integral, and the * is supposed to mean "F star". Sorry about that. Could you explain to me the process for finding the matrix for a standard basis then doing the change of basis? The last part of my question requires me to use the matrix to calculate the derivative of 4x^3 - 4. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK.  I've fixed the equation in your question.  In the future, try to learn some [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can do it yourself.  As for finding the matrix -- you'll find $FY_0$, $FY_1$, and $FY_2$ in terms of the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$.  Then your standard matrix will be the coeff's of those vectors as the columns.  The change of basis matrices will be $\pmatrix{Y_0 & Y_1 & Y_2}$ (again, coeff's as columns) and the inverse of this matrix.  Then just multiply $\Lambda^{-1} M\Lambda$.

Comment: For more info on change of basis, you can read my answers to these questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564507/how-do-i-find-the-matrix-with-respect-to-a-different-basis/1564625#1564625), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460141/on-the-change-of-coordinates-of-a-matrix).

Comment: Hi Bye World, Thank you for your help. I have bookmarked the MathJax link so I can begin learning it. Can you explain to me how the integral comes into play with this at all? It seems like it is not even needed then, right? Thanks.

Comment: It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the linear operator to the basis vectors, these will be the column of your matrix
$$
(y_0)'=0\\
(y_1)'=\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{40}}{3^{3/2}}y_0\\
(y_2)''=25x=25\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}y_1
$$
yielding
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{\sqrt{40}}{3^{3/2}}&0\\0&0&25\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Hi Bye World, Is this correct then? This seems to be a fairly straight forward problem then.

Comment: Hi Bye World, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bye World,I have one more question- I made a typo in the last part of the question, I have to use the matrix to find the deivative of 4x^2. How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: @Bye_World good call, fixing

Comment: @MoparGuy Apply the matrix to $4x^2$ as expressed wrt your basis $\{y_0,y_1,y_2\}$.

Comment: Hi Bye World, can you explain more on what you mean? I apologize , I am trying really hard to understand this.